# Android - Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText

Tags: java, android, xml

guys I seem to be getting an odd error for the signed apk of an app I'm working on. At first I thought it was because I added support for java 1.8 but then it ran on the debug version flawlessly from 4.1 throught 7.1.

- minSdkVersion 16
- targetSdkVersion 27
- compileSdkVersion 27
- buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

I've not used any background property in my xml layout so I'm not sure what's the problem.

I'm running Android Studio 3.0.1

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dita.dev.myportal/dita.dev.myportal.ui.login.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
 at abp.b(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
 at dita.dev.myportal.ui.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:38)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
 at abp.b(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
 at dita.dev.myportal.ui.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:38) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.setBackgroundDrawable(AppCompatEditText.java:86)
 at android.view.View.setBackground(View.java:15322)
 at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3874)
 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:623)
 at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:60)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:64)
 at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:60)
 at android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText.<init>(TextInputEditText.java:41)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
 at abp.b(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
 at dita.dev.myportal.ui.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:38) 
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".ui.login.LoginActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:padding="24dp"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.6"
                android:contentDescription="@string/my_portal_logo"
                android:padding="40dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:hintEnabled="false">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    style="@style/LoginEditStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/username"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:padding="8dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                app:passwordToggleTint="@android:color/white">

                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    style="@style/LoginEditStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLength="30"
                    android:padding="8dp" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login"
                style="@style/LoginButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/login" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Here are the gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    //compile files('libs/poi-3.14.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart-Realm:v2.0.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.9'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    implementation 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.0'
    implementation 'com.rollbar:rollbar-android:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you, without the code?

Comment: @SaranSankaran I've added the xml code.

Comment: looks like something wrong with the style. Can you try removing the style and run the app and see if its crash. Also, can you post the used style as well?